# Shortcut to display the preview of all workspaces in unity

Tags: 16.04, unity, mac, workspaces, dock

In unity, does anyone know a shortcut to display the preview of all workspaces (as if you clicked the button of the workspaces on the dock)?

I sometimes would like to have an overview of which desktops are already occupied or not before moving to another desktop. So far, to achieve that, I have to click on the button of the workspaces (on the dock).

*I am currently using an Ubuntu VM on a Mac OS X host.*

Answer (score 2):

Use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. You can find (and change) the shortcut using the CompizConfig Settings Manager (ccsm), under Desktop > Expo > Expo Key.

Comment: I have edited my question. I forgot to say that I am using an Ubuntu VM on a Mac OS. Command + S doesn't seem to work: it opens a window to show the current snapshots. In fact, Command + S is a shortcut of the hypervisor I am using.

Comment: Do you have the CompizConfig Settings Manager installed? If yes, you can see which shortcut it defines, and change it. If you don't have ccsm you can install it with `sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager`.

Comment: CompizConfig actually reports me that the shortcut related to Expo Key is `<Super>s`. I am not sure which key is the super key on the Mac. I suppose it should be "command", but it isn't working (as I said above).

Answer (score 0):

to view all workspace :
    ctrl + alt + upperArrowKey

to switch between workspaces
    ctrl + alt + left|right-arrow-key